# org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

почему то даже по синтаксису таймлиф подсвечивает ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой контроллер[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

модель -

```
public Book(){

}

public Book(String name, String author, int year){
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.year = year;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year){
    this.year=year;
}

public String getAuthor(){
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author){
    this.author = author;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
```

`

полный текст ошибки:

```
    `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/people/index.html]")
    org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:235)
    org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:649)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362)
    org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:502)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:596)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/people/index.html]
    org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:159)
    org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.reader(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:103)
    org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:223)
    org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:649)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362)
    org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:502)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:596)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)`
```